# Probability of a lone radioactive decay event in a window of time

Tags: probability

Imagine I have $N$ isolated clusters of atoms undergoing radioactive decay, where the probability per time step of a decay event is $p$ (assume each cluster can have an arbitrary number of decay events with the same fixed probability).  Let $t$ be the duration of a time step.  As a function of $p$, what is the probability of having a single decay event, and then having no further decay events for at least $k-1$ additional time steps?  What will be the mean duration between decays as a function of $p$?

Let me attempt a partial answer:

If we have a decay event, the probability that none of the other clusters will decay in that same time interval is $(1 - p)^{(N-1)}$.  The probability that there are no further decays for the remaining $(k-1)$ time steps is $\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(1 - p)^{N}$, yielding:

P(a single decay followed by no decays for $k-1$ additional time steps) = $(1 - p)^{(N-1)} * \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(1 - p)^{N} = \frac{((1-p)^N)^k}{(1-p)}$.

In terms of the time distribution between between events, we can use the negative binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), setting the number of acceptable failures (decay events) as $r = 1$, the success probability (no decay event for a time step) as $s = (1-p)^N$, and then write the mean number of time steps between decay events as:

E(time steps between decay events) = $\frac{sr}{1-s} = \frac{(1-p)^N}{1-(1-p)^N}$

Comment: Your perspective and attempts as thoughts in an additional paragraph will garner more response.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I have attempted a partial answer.